# Indexing for a changing number python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing

I'm trying to figure out the index for this program. I want it to print a number for each letter entered in the input, for example the string "Jon" would be:

"10 15 14"

but I keep getting an error with the for loop I created with the indexes. If anyone has any thoughts on how to fix this it would be great help!

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5
f = 6
g = 7
h = 8
i = 9
j = 10
k = 11
l = 12 
m = 13
n = 14
o = 15 
p = 16 
q = 17 
r = 18 
s = 19 
t = 20 
u = 21 
v = 22 
w = 23 
x = 24 
y = 25 
z = 26

name = input("Name: ")

lowercase = name.lower()

print("Your 'cleaned up' name is:", lowercase)
print("Your 'cleaned up name reduces to:")

length = len(name)

name1 = 0
for x in range(name[0], name[length]):
    print(name[name1])
    name1 += 1
```

Comment: `name` is a string. Why are you passing strings to `range()`?

Comment: Also, note that you can improve this code by using a dictionary to map characters to numbers. Here's a one-liner to map strings to their numeric component: `dict(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1,27))`. Make sure to do `import string` first.

Comment: Because i don't have a set range, it depends on the length of the word that the user inputs... is there another way of going about this/is what I did wrong?

Comment: @DannyGarcia Note that name is an iterable and supports `for character in name` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save yourself all those variables, and not even need a dictionary by just utilizing `ord` here and calculating the numerical position in the alphabet:

Example: Taking letter c, which using the following should give us 3:

```
>>> ord('c') - 96
3
```

ord will:

> Return the integer ordinal of a one-character string.

The 96 is used because of the positions of the alphabet on the ascii table.

So, with that in mind. When you enter a word, using your example: "Jon"

```
word = input("enter name")
print(*(ord(c) - 96 for c in name.lower()))
# 10 15 14
```

Comment: Or just `print(*(ord(c) - 96 for c in name.lower()))`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Nice catch. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can store each letter and the indices in a dict so you can easily retrieve the ones in `name`:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> letters = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, range(1, len(ascii_lowercase) + 1)))
>>> for c in name:
...    print(letters[c])
```

If you want indices lined up in the string:

```
>>> print(" ".join(str(letters[c]) for c in name))
"10 15 14"
```

Comment: `range(1, len(ascii_lowercase))`, should be `range(1, len(ascii_lowercase)+1)`

Answer (score 1):

You are currently passing characters to `range()`. `range(name[0], name[length])` with a name of `'Jon'` is equivalent to `range('J', 'n')`... or it would be if strings were 1-indexed. Unfortunately for this code snippet, a sequence does not have an element with an index equal to the sequence's length. The last element of a three-character string has an index of two, not three. Your algorithm also has zero interaction with the letter values you defined above. It has little chance of succeeding.

Rather than defining each letter's value separately, store it in a string and then look up each letter's index in that string:

```
name = input('Name: ')
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
print(*(s.index(c)+1 for c in name.lower()))
```

A generator that produces the index of each of the name's characters in the master string (plus one, because you want it one-indexed) is unpacked and sent to `print()`, which, with the default separator of a space, produces the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than define 26 different variables, how about using a dictionary? Then you can write something like:

```
mapping = {
    'a': 1,
    # etc
}

name_in_numbers = ' '.join(mapping[letter] for letter in name)
```

Note that this will break for any input that doesn't only contain letters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must use a `dict` to store the mapping of characters to `int`, you may use, `string` module to access all the lowercase characters, it makes your code less error prone. Secondly you just need to iterate over the characters in the lowercase string and access the mapped values as `int` from the given mapping:

```
import string

mapping = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1, len(string.ascii_lowercase)+1)))


name = "Anmol"
lowercase = name.lower()

print("Your 'cleaned up' name is:", lowercase)
print("Your 'cleaned up name reduces to:")

for char in lowercase:
    print mapping[char],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# make up a data structure to not pollute the namespace with 26 variable names; a dictionary does well for this
dict={}
for i in range(97,123):
    dict[chr(i)]=i-96

print dict

name=raw_input("Name: ")
name=name.lower()

for i in name:
    print dict[i],
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'g': 7, 'f': 6, 'i': 9, 'h': 8, 'k': 11, 'j': 10, 'm': 13, 'l': 12, 'o': 15, 'n': 14, 'q': 17, 'p': 16, 's': 19, 'r': 18, 'u': 21, 't': 20, 'w': 23, 'v': 22, 'y': 25, 'x': 24, 'z': 26}
Name: Jon
10 15 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer that you build a mapping of `char:index`, that you can always refer to later, this way:

```
>>> ascii_chrs = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> d = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(ascii_chrs, 1)}
>>> d
{'q': 17, 'i': 9, 'u': 21, 'x': 24, 'a': 1, 's': 19, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'e': 5, 'v': 22, 'b': 2, 'p': 16, 'g': 7, 'o': 15, 'j': 10, 't': 20, 'h': 8, 'f': 6, 'r': 18, 'y': 25, 'c': 3, 'k': 11, 'd': 4, 'z': 26, 'w': 23, 'l': 12}
>>>
>>> word = 'Salam'
>>> print(*(d[c] for c in word.lower()))
19 1 12 1 13
```